# Not found route not found in Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, routes, sails.js

Based on [Sailsjs documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes), it is possible to add on the routes file a response with a syntax like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {
    '/foo': {response: 'notFound'}
};
```

This searches for the `notFound.js` file in the `/response` directory, which I've in there.

So in my `routes.js` file I've added this as the end of the other routes in order to catch the not found routes, it is something like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {
    'get  /myroute/:myPara/': 'MyController.getAll',
    'get  /myroute/:myPara/': 'MyController.getOne',
    'post /myroute/:myPara/': 'MyController.create',
    '/*' : {response: 'notFound'}
};
```

I've realized that never finds the last route, I've also tried removing the slash ( doing `'*'` ), but nothing works.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sails already take care of the 404 notFound : [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/middleware/conventional-defaults)

Sails call res.notFound() and you can override the default notFound():

> `res.notFound()` (like other userland response methods) can be overridden or modified. It runs the response method defined in /responses/notFound.js, which is bundled automatically in newly generated Sails apps. If a notFound.js response method does not exist in your app, Sails will implicitly use the default behavior.